# How accurate is share my location

Tags: iphone, geolocation

With a cell tower in sight about a 3/4 of a mile away how accurate is the share my location if the phone is in a Walmart

Answer (score 0):

It's going to vary, of course, but one way to get an approximation is to pull up the Maps app.

[This article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203033) from Apple Support says the following about this...

> "Apps that can show your location on the screen, including Maps, show your current (approximate) location using a blue marker. If your location can't be determined precisely, you'll see a blue circle around the marker. The size of the circle shows how precisely your location can be determined—the smaller the circle, the greater the precision."

This article may be of assistance, too: http://n8henrie.com/2014/09/how-accurate-is-the-iphone-gps/

Comment: There's more to it than that. It can only use true GPS if it can see the sky; it will also use crowd-sourced WiFi & cell-phone towers to supplement that data if it can't get a good GPS fix.

Comment: The first article I posted goes into that. I've been able to use "Find My Friends" to locate my husband in Costco and our 2-story Target when I really thought it wouldn't work. It's an amazing tool.